# Local variable initialization behavior C++

Tags: c++, c++11, local-variables

this piece of code:

```
int findsmallerNumber(int low, int high, string *str)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string ss = *str;

    for(int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++)
    {
        if(ss[i] < ss[low])
            counter++;
    }
    cout<<counter<<" ";
    return counter;
}
```

produces the correct output as:

```
4 4 3 1 1 0
```

but when the counter variable **isn't initialized** as such:

```
int counter;
```

the output obtained is:

```
4 8 11 12 13 13
```

**Can someone please explain this behavior?**

Comment: btw it is unclear how the output with the correct code can start with `4 ...` when `counter` is `0`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry that cout wasn't supposed to be there :(. Have edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please explain this behavior?

The value of an uninitialised variable is indeterminate. If you read an indeterminate value, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. That explains the behaviour that you observe. Don't read indeterminate values.